# Index number is connected with multiple slides, and cannot handle with them independently

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Background

I made slides which are appeared on a modal, and its main functions are below.

- There are "←Prev, Next→" buttons, and it enables to flip the page.
- There are page numbers, "1, 2, 3", and it enables to flip the page.
- If the shown page is the first or the last one, "←Prev, Next→" buttons are hidden, respectively.

Those functions were working properly when I had only one slide with the code below, but the last funtion doesn't work with multiple slides now.

**slide.html.erb**

```
<ul>
  <li><div data-target="slide01">Slide1</div>
    <div id="slide01" class="modal-wrapper">
      <div class="modal">
        <div class="close-modal">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-wrapper">
          <div class="slide-title">Slide1</div>
          <div class="change-btn-wrapper">
            <div class="change-btn prev-btn">← Prev</div>
            <div class="change-btn next-btn">Next →</div>
          </div>
          <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide active">A</li>
            <li class="slide">B</li>
            <li class="slide">C</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="index-btn-wrapper">
            <div class="index-btn">1</div>
            <div class="index-btn">2</div>
            <div class="index-btn">3</div>                 
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>   

  <li><div data-target="slide02">Slide2</div>
    <div id="slide02" class="modal-wrapper">
      <div class="modal">
        <div class="close-modal">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-times"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="slide-wrapper">
          <div class="slide-title">Slide2</div>
          <div class="change-btn-wrapper">
            <div class="change-btn prev-btn">← Prev</div>
            <div class="change-btn next-btn">Next →</div>
          </div>
          <ul class="slides">
            <li class="slide active">D</li>
            <li class="slide">E</li>
            <li class="slide">F</li>
          </ul>
          <div class="index-btn-wrapper">
            <div class="index-btn">1</div>
            <div class="index-btn">2</div>
            <div class="index-btn">3</div>                 
          </div> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

**slide.js**

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(function() {
    function toggleChangeBtn(){
      var slideIndex = $('.slide').index($('.active'));
      $('.change-btn').show();
      if (slideIndex == 0) {
        $('.prev-btn').hide();
      } else if (slideIndex == $('.slide').length -1) {
        $('.next-btn').hide();
      }

    $('.index-btn').click(function() {
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      var clickedIndex = $('.index-btn').index($(this));
      $('.slide').eq(clickedIndex).addClass('active');
      toggleChangeBtn();
    });

    $('.change-btn').click(function() {
      var $displaySlide = $('.active');
      $displaySlide.removeClass('active');
      if ($(this).hasClass('next-btn')) {
        $displaySlide.next().addClass('active');
      }
      else {
        $displaySlide.prev().addClass('active');
      }
      toggleChangeBtn(); 
    });
  })
});
```

#### Problems

Those codes below check if the shown page is the first or the last one from its index number, and hide "←Prev, Next→" buttons, respectively.

**slide.js**

```js
var slideIndex = $('.slide').index($('.active'));
$('.change-btn').show();
if (slideIndex == 0) {
  $('.prev-btn').hide();
} else if (slideIndex == $('.slide').length -1) {
  $('.next-btn').hide();
}
```

The trouble is that those index numbers are connected when multiple slides are made. As a result, the code above just checks only both of the first page in the first slide and the last page in the last slide.

#### What I have tried

I tried to use `$(this).parents` method to narrow down the range of the slide like below. I did not make any change on the view.

**slide.js**

```js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $(function() {
    function toggleChangeBtn(dir){
      var dir = $(this).parents('.slide-wrapper'); // Identify the slide.   
      $('.change-btn').show();
      var slideIndex = dir.find('.slide').dir.index('.active');
      if (slideIndex == 0) {
        dir.find('.prev-btn').hide();
      } else if (slideIndex == dir.find('.slide').length -1) {
        dir.find('.next-btn').hide();
      }
    }

    $('.index-btn').click(function() {
      var dir = $(this).parents('.slide-wrapper'); 
      dir.find('.active').removeClass('active');
      var clickedIndex = $('.index-btn').index($(this));
      $('.slide').eq(clickedIndex).addClass('active');
      toggleChangeBtn(dir);
    });

    $('.change-btn').click(function() {
      var dir = $(this).parents('.slide-wrapper');
      var $displaySlide = dir.find('.active');
      $displaySlide.removeClass('active');
      if ($(this).hasClass('next-btn')) {
        $displaySlide.next().addClass('active');
      }
      else {
        $displaySlide.prev().addClass('active');
      }
      toggleChangeBtn(dir); 
    });
  })
});
```

However, "←Prev, Next→" buttons are not hidden properly in any slide with this code.
And how "←Prev, Next→" buttons are shown in one slide affects to the other slide too.
I am grateful if anyone gives me some advice.

#### Versions

ruby 2.6.4p104
RubyGems 3.0.3
Rails 5.2.3
jquery 1.12.4

Answer (score 0):

If both buttons should be independent of each other, why are they made dependant by the if / else if block?

```js
if (slideIndex == 0) {
  dir.find('.prev-btn').hide();
} else if (slideIndex == dir.find('.slide').length -1) {
  dir.find('.next-btn').hide();
}
```

To make the `.prev-btn` and `.next-btn` appear/disappear independently, make these independant if statements:

```js
var slides = dir.find('.slide');
var slideIndex = slides.length ? slides.dir.index('.active') : 0;
if (slideIndex == 0) {
  dir.find('.prev-btn').hide();
}

if (slides.length <= 1 || slideIndex == slides.length - 1) {
  dir.find('.next-btn').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your "if block" is much clearer.
I tried with this code, but `.hide()` did not work on both of prev and next buttons.

The meaning of this code below is like this, right?
1. if slide exists (true), substitute the index number of the current slide for `slideIndex`.
2. if slide does not exist (false), substitute 0 for slideIndex.（means both buttons should not be displayed.）

`var slideIndex = slides.length ? slides.dir.index('.active') : 0;`

I guess the code is right, but I could not find the reason why it does not work..

Comment: You're welcome. This is correct, yes. I made the code a little clearer where the slides and were the index are used. The main problem with your old code is that the else if prevents the next button from being hidden when you are on slideIndex 0, which is always the case at the beginning. The `.hide()` calls were taken from your original code so I couldn't tell you why that would not work.